# Create JSON object with same keys for API call

Tags: javascript, json, api, object

I'm trying to create a JSON object for an API call which has the following format:

```
  ....
  "Key": "Value",
  "Package": {
    "Dimensions": {
      "UnitOfMeasurement": {
        "Code": "IN",
        "Description": "inches"
      },
      "Length": "20",
      "Width": "25",
      "Height": "30"
    },
    "PackageWeight": {
      "UnitOfMeasurement": {
        "Code": "Lbs",
        "Description": "pounds"
      },
      "Weight": "80"
    }
  },
  "Package": {
    "Dimensions": {
      "UnitOfMeasurement": {
        "Code": "IN",
        "Description": "inches"
      },
      "Length": "15",
      "Width": "24",
      "Height": "27"
    },
    "PackageWeight": {
      "UnitOfMeasurement": {
        "Code": "Lbs",
        "Description": "pounds"
      },
      "Weight": "50"
    }
  },
  "Key": "Value",
  ....
```

I should add as many "Package" objects as needed. However, I've tried doing this in many different ways but every time that I parse the variable to be used the first objects get overwritten and I end up with only the last object.

This is what I'm trying at the moment, still with no luck:

```
var lineItems = '{';
  for (var i=0;i<inputObject.packages.length;i++) {
      lineItems += '"Package": {"PackagingType": {"Code": "02","Description": "Rate"},"Dimensions": {"UnitOfMeasurement": {"Code": "IN","Description": "inches"},"Length": ' + inputObject.packages[i][0].toString() + ',"Width": ' + inputObject.packages[i][1].toString() + ',"Height": ' + inputObject.packages[i][2].toString() + '},"PackageWeight": {"UnitOfMeasurement": {"Code": "Lbs","Description": "pounds"},"Weight": ' + inputObject.packages[i][3].toString() + '}}';
      if (i !== inputObject.packages.length-1) {
          lineItems += ',';
      }
  }

  lineItems += '}';

  lineItems = JSON.parse(lineItems);
```

Comment: That's invalid JSON. You cannot have duplicate keys (you have multiple "Package" keys, which is invalid).

Comment: Why do you build up a string and parse it to objects? Cant you build the objects directly??

Comment: Yeah, it's invalid JSON but I'm looking for a way around it. I've tried creating objects directly but the same thing happens

Comment: Read the documentation of the API closely; it likely has something more like `"Packages": [ {"PackagingType": ... } ]`. In other words, `Packages` is an array, not a bunch of properties with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

How about numbering your packages, ie:

```
             for (var i=0;i<inputObject.packages.length;i++) {
                   lineItems+='"Package" + i : { ... }'
                  }
```

edit: to get required result (as an array - because it's not JSON), here's an example:

```js
var a=[];
var b={"package": {"c":100,"d":200,"e":300}}
var c={"package": {"c":800,"d":700,"e":600}}
a.push(b);
a.push(c);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: That's a good idea, if in the end I could remove the numbers somehow